# JS function split not working letters uppercase

Tags: javascript

Example 1:

```
var string_1 = "My name is Tom Jelly";
var param = string_1.split('Tom');
console.log(param);
```

> ["My name is ", " Jelly"]

Example 2:

```
var string_2 = "My name is tom Jelly";
var param = string_2.split('Tom');
console.log(param);
```

> ["My name is tom Jelly"]

How can I get the result as Example 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regexp as a separator with `i` flag (case insensitive):

```
string_2.split(/Tom/i);
```

Comment: Note: to use a variable, use `new Regex`.

Comment: I'm just surprised, I'm unable to find a relevant dupe for this post. This seems to be a fairly common issue.

Comment: How can i add a parameter, I'm a beginner, please give me specific example. Thanks you

Comment: Thanks you verry much

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `.split()` is case insensitive.
so,

```
var param = string_2.split('Tom');
```

should be like

```
var param = string_2.split('tom');
```